# debug xap faster in performance than release xap?

Tags: debugging, release, xap, ndebug

WP8 app

After debugging and releasing the app, I've tried to run the xap of both on different devices,
apparently that the debug xap is way faster than the release xap.
The method I used is by deploying the xap, not through VS12.
If anyone would like to why would I do this, because when I use the VS12 debugging or releasing mode to deploy the app, it works fine and relatively fast for both.
But surprisingly, and as I expected, when I used the (release) xap itself that I uploaded to the store, it was really slow, while the (debug) xap is really fast.
And don't tell me it's because the debug mode VS12, because I haven't use the VS12 when I deployed the app, and it showed this difference!!!.

So my question would be:
is it possible to upload the debug xap to the store?
And if not, what shall I do to modify the debug xap to be recognized as released xap to be ready to upload to the store?

Thanks in advance for any helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upload debug xaps too... If you are doing a hard-performance app, then it should be release to make it faster, otherwise it can crash and be denied...